# Why is my method returning false?

Tags: php, postgresql, class, methods

I am trying to create an instance of a class "announcement".

For example:

```
$announcement = new announcement;
//code to bind data
$announcement->store();
```

My store function runs a query to store the information to the database. Everything is working as intended and storing to my database. However when I say:

```
if($announcement->store())
{
    echo 'success';
}
else{
    echo 'failure';
}
```

I get the 'failure' message. Why is my method returning false when it is actually working? Am I missing something with conditional statements and methods?

**UPDATE**
My store function was not returning anything. So even though it worked it was returning a null value. I return true on query success and now it is working as intended. Thank you.

Comment: what does store() return?

Comment: @MindYaBidness you will need to provide us with the implementation of the `store` method for us to be able to understand why that method is returning false.

Comment: `var_dump($accountment->store())` and see what it's actually returning. If it's returning false (which is more than likely the case), we'll need the source of `->store` to help further.

Comment: All my store method does is run a query. When I set var_dump($announcement->store()) is get 'NULL'. Should I set the store method to return true?

Comment: It should return whatever the status of the query is, so that you can tell if `$announcement->store()` was actually successful or not. IE, false if there was an issue inserting the data into the database, or true if not.

Comment: `NULL` is false-ish, thus your if statement will never echo `success`. You have to return `true` or `false` depending if the query was successful or not.

Comment: Does the function return anything? If you have a function that doesn't `return` anything (even if it `echo`s something), it will return `NULL` - and `if (NULL)` is the same as `if (false)`. We can't really help you without seeing that function, so share your full, relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

The store function should `return true` then your statement will print `success` message

```
class announcement {
    public function store() {
        // after execution code the return value should be like this
        return true;
    }
}
```